# What is the best practice for split result rows before process it?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, chunks

I am trying to create an email blaster for more than 100k emails at once using the Laravel framework.

My command:

```
public function handle()
{
    $blastId = $this->argument('blast');

    $blast = Blast::find($blastId);
    activity()->performedOn($blast)->log('Blast is sending');
    foreach ($blast->unsentLogs as $log) {
        try {
            Mail::queue((new BlastEmail($log))->onQueue('emails'));
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            activity('send_failed')->performedOn($log->contact)->causedBy($log)->log('Email send failed: '.$e->getMessage());
        }
    }
    $blast->status = 'sent';
    $blast->save();
    activity()->performedOn($blast)->log('Blast is sent');

    return 0;
}
```

my blast mail construct:

```
public function __construct(BlastLog $log)
{
    $contact = $log->contact;
    $blast = $log->blast;
    $this->content = $blast->content;
    $this->content = str_replace('**UNSUB**', 'https://urltounsubscribe.com', $this->content);
    $this->subject = $blast->subject;
    $this->to($contact->email, "Name");
    $this->from($blast->from_email, $blast->from_name);
    $log->sent_at = now();
    $log->save();
}
```

My code can handle under 1000 emails in 30 seconds, but why does it take a long time to send about 100k emails? It should only need 3000 seconds to handle 100k emails, but it's more than 3 hours and still not completed. How to improve my code?

I think the problem is `$blast->unsentLogs`, it has more than 100k collection rows, make it takes a lot amount of RAM.

Maybe I need to split `$blast->unsentLogs` to some parts/chunks. But what is the best practice for doing that? It should be using a query builder right? But I don't have idea to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your issue is clearly in `$blast->unsentLogs`. PHP cannot handle 100k `collections`, that is hell a lot...

You should `chunk` the results instead of getting them all at once...

Your code should be like:

```php
public function handle()
{
    $blastId = $this->argument('blast');

    $blast = Blast::find($blastId);
    activity()->performedOn($blast)->log('Blast is sending');
    $blast->unsentLogs()->chunk(100, function (Collection $logs) {
        foreach ($logs as $log) {
            try {
                Mail::queue((new BlastEmail($log))->onQueue('emails'));
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                activity('send_failed')->performedOn($log->contact)->causedBy($log)->log('Email send failed: '.$e->getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
    $blast->status = 'sent';
    $blast->save();
    activity()->performedOn($blast)->log('Blast is sent');

    return 0;
}
```

Read more about [`chunk`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#chunking-results).

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks. I know that `chunk` function since a long a time ago, but never use it and forgot it when needed. LoL . btw you said `PHP cannot handle 100k collections` but actually can handle it. My old code campaign finished 4 hours to handle 100k collection. XD

Comment: hahaha, what I meant with `PHP cannot handle 100k collections` is that it cannot handle it in a desired time span, 4 hours is a lot of time. What is the current time ? 10 minutes or less ?

Comment: Now it's needed 3 hours for handling 250k data, maybe still a lot, but it's a far better and only use small amount of RAM.